# How to find all ELB name that are using specific VPC in AWS via boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, vpc, amazon-elb

I want to filter and list ELBs with specific vpcid using boto3. Using that ELB name I want to delete that ELB using boto3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('elbv2', region="ap_southeast_2")

response = client.describe_load_balancers()

# Get ELBs
for elb in response['LoadBalancers']:
    if elb['VpcId'] == 'vpc-xxx':
        # Delete ELB
        client.delete_load_balancer(LoadBalancerArn=elb['LoadBalancerArn'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

elb_client = boto3.client('elbv2', region="us-west-2")

elbs = elb_client.describe_load_balancers()['LoadBalancers']

elbs = [elb['LoadBalancerArn'] for elb in elbs if elb['VpcId'] == 'vpc-xxxxxxxx']

for elb in elbs:
    elb_client.delete_load_balancer(LoadBalancerArn=elb)
```